# CSS in Symfony 2

Tags: html, css, symfony

in `index.html.twig`

```
{% extends 'CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cvutfitbiwt1poll/css/style.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Text</h2>
...
```

in `layout.html.twig`

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/cvutfitbiwt1poll/css/style.css') }}"
{% endblock %}
```

css I have in src/......./Resources/public/css/style.css

in `style.css`

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
label, input[type="submit"] {
display: block;
padding: 0.5em;
}      
h2{
color:blue;
}
```

I didn't see any css

Thanks for help

Comment: And what's in your base.html.twig?

Comment: Did you run `php app/console assets:install web/`?

Comment: `app/console assets:install web` 
works
thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php app/console assets:install         --Installs bundles web assets under a public web directory

you need run this command to copy files(css js img) to the web directory

Comment: `app/console assets:install web` 
works
thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Your blocks are defined wrong.

This will solve it:
in index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'CvutFitBiWt1PollBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/cvutfitbiwt1poll/css/style.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<h2>Text</h2>
```

in layout.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/cvutfitbiwt1poll/css/style.css') }}"
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why overriding the stylesheets block within your index.html.twig template to include the same file (style.css is already included in your layout.html.twig)?

Comment: oh i dint notice it. Thanks